# Issue with FastAPI swagger ui for formdata array param?

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui

[image: Swagger UI]
[image: debug]

My issue is that I want the parameter video_urls to be an array of strings, rather than a single string array.

When using Postman to send the parameters, everything works as expected, but Swagger, for some reason, sends the parameters separated by commas.

Is this something I did wrong, or is it a bug that is out of my control? And how can I fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)